# Build APK is getting crashed when trying to login. Due to Exception " Unable to load asset "

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, crash, runtimeexception

Exception :
[image: Exception here]

My Folder structure :
[image: folder structure]

Puspec.yaml file :
[image: my yaml file]

Comment: Run in debug mode and share error logs for better understanding of your problem statement. Also, share your code where it is throwing error

Comment: Error logs is there in Exception image.

Comment: Exception is coming from just starting application. which code part you need ?

Answer (score 0):

1. check the image file location in your code,
2. check the file name of the image,
3. check the `pubspec.yaml` assets indentation, try to rearrange, add space or remove space
4. rebuild your app, do `flutter clean` too

Comment: I've done all this things, but no results.

Comment: can you share your code for getting the image ?

Comment: Hello, thank you but no need now. as I was working with co-dev and she created custom widget which was causing the trouble with null value checked.